# PHP error with "logger.php" - Unknown: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using Visual Studio Code with PHP Server extension. When I try to launch my Web application, the browser shows me this message:

> **Warning**: Unknown: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **Unknown** on line **0**
>
> **Fatal error**: Failed opening required 'c:\Users\OMISSIS\.vscode\extensions\brapifra.phpserver-3.0.2\src\server\logger.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in **Unknown** on line **0**

I also tried to reinstall VS Code and XAMPP but the problem persists. What can I do?

Comment: P.S. I posted this Q&A because I saw many students dealing with this error without finding solution for it on the Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the file `logger.php` (belonging to the PHP Server extension) is missing.

The solution is creating it (in the path indicated in the error message) with the following content:

```php
<?php
$path = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);
$relativePath = getenv('PHP_SERVER_RELATIVE_PATH');
$fullPath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $relativePath . $path;
if (!file_exists($fullPath) || is_dir($fullPath)) {
    file_put_contents("php://stderr", sprintf("[%s] %s", date("D M j H:i:s Y"), "[404] $path - No such file or directory "));
}
else {
    file_put_contents("php://stdout", sprintf("[%s] %s", date("D M j H:i:s Y"), "[200] $path"));
}
return false;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my student case, the antivirus was blocking and putting it in quarantine. It was even blocking me to create the file, then I figured it out that something was blocking the file to be created, it was the Avast!

Thanks for posting this question, it did help me to figure out the problem!